# flyer_sim package

Tags: ros, quadcopter, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking for a quadrotor simulator, and found the starmac flyer_sim package on the ROS wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/flyer_sim

The linked repo however does not contain the flyer_sim package any more. Also the starmac_flyer stack does not list it any longer. What happened to the flyer_sim package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11194/flyer_sim-package/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like `flyer_sim` got moved to the `simulated_quadrotor` package in the repo.

See [starmac-ros-pkg:c0accc574817](https://bitbucket.org/bouffard/starmac-ros-pkg/changeset/c0accc574817) for details.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-09-15**:
Thanks! I took the liberty to add the missing wiki page for it: http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulated_quadrotor

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For electic and ubuntu:

roslaunch simulated_quadrotor sim.launch show_plots:=false

---

Originally posted by [Joaquín](https://answers.ros.org/users/1342/joaqu%C3%ADn/) with karma: 11 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1